# How to install an APK file on an Android phone?

Tags: android

I have a simple "Hello Android" application on my computer ([Eclipse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_%28software%29) environment), and I have built an [APK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APK_%28file_format%29) file. How do I transfer the APK file to my Android phone for testing?

My phone is [Ideos](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huawei_U8800) running Android 2.2 (Froyo). My laptop has Windows Vista. I have the latest Android SDK installed.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I quote Hello Android because I can't say it better ;-)

> You need to enable USB debugging on the phone itself (by starting the Settings application and selecting *Applications* > *Development* > *USB Debugging*), install the Android USB device driver if you haven’t already (Windows only), and then plug the phone into your computer using the USB cable that came with the phone.
>
> Close the emulator window if it’s already open. As long as the phone is plugged in, Eclipse will load and run applications on the phone instead. You need to right-click the project and select *Run As* > *Android Application*.

Comment: How can i download the usb_drivers, my eclipse avd manager->Available package has no option of "USB drivers"

Comment: just simply dnld. usb drivers from internet and install it

Comment: NOTE: In Android 4.2 the "Development" menu is hidden. This video shows how to turn it back on http://youtu.be/mp07dPusJNA

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.. it just shows another way to install the app in the device.

Answer (score 290):

Simply, you use [ADB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Debug_Bridge), as follows:

```
adb install <path to apk>
```

Also see the section *Installing an Application* in *[Android Debug Bridge](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html)*.

Comment: If the app already exists on the device, you may need to use the `-r` option in order to reinstall it.

Comment: You might also need to uninstall the app completely for it to install successfully. Using the `-r` option didn't do the trick for me.

Comment: Also of value is to use the `-d` option if you have a simulator also running. So, the command is `adb -d install -r <path_to_apk>`.

Comment: is it possible to install apk if the file is on the android device?

Comment: yes, u just click on that apk and then you will get the android native install prompt

Comment: I am not sure ,May be the user who ask this question not getting exact answer from this answer

Comment: @Joshua Pinter Don't just write some cryptic parameters. Explain them: "If you have multiple devices available, but only one is an emulator, use the -e option to send commands to the emulator. Likewise, if there are multiple devices but only one hardware device attached, use the -d option to send commands to the hardware device." https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb

Comment: @TheincredibleJan You're right! That's actually a huge pet peeve of mine, so thanks for correcting!

Answer (score 75):

If you have access to a Gmail account on the phone then an easy way (in terms of minimal set up effort) is to mail the .apk file to that Gmail account.

If you then access that account from the native Gmail app on the phone it recognises that the attachment is an app and offers an "Install" button.

As per other responses this approach also requires that you have selected USB debugging on the device.

Try this - it is remarkably easy ;-)

Comment: That is awesome---thanks! Now I'll be able to easily update the custom app I've installed on my Grandma's tablet.

Comment: The Phone should not be connected to USB storage while the application is being installed using this method. If it is connected then the Gmail App crashes, since SD card is required to save the file. Just a note :)

Comment: No, this method does not require that "USB debugging" be enabled, but it does require that "Unknown Sources" be enabled.

Comment: +1 for a nice low-tech solution. I had to use drive because gmail blocked me from sending an APK file though.

Answer (score 21):

If you dont have SDK or you are setting up 3rd party app here is another way:

1. Copy the .APK file to your device.
2. Use file manager to locate the file.
3. Then click on it.
4. Android App installer should be one of the options in pop-up.
5. Select it and it installs.

Comment: Use this way for 3rd party apps and you dont have sdk.

Comment: Works on mac osx el capitan. In the terminal, type in : adb install /Users/Simon/Documents/MyApp/app/build/outputs/apk/app-debug.apk

Answer (score 13):

outside device,we can use :

```
adb install file.apk
```

or `adb install -r file.apk`

```
  adb install [-l] [-r] [-s] [--algo <algorithm name> --key <hex-encoded key> --iv <hex-encoded iv>] <file>
                               - push this package file to the device and install it
                                 ('-l' means forward-lock the app)
                                 ('-r' means reinstall the app, keeping its data)
                                 ('-s' means install on SD card instead of internal storage)
                                 ('--algo', '--key', and '--iv' mean the file is encrypted already)
```

---

inside devices also, we can use:

```
pm install file.apk
```

or `pm install -r file.apk`

```
pm install: installs a package to the system.  Options:
    -l: install the package with FORWARD_LOCK.
    -r: reinstall an exisiting app, keeping its data.
    -t: allow test .apks to be installed.
    -i: specify the installer package name.
    -s: install package on sdcard.
    -f: install package on internal flash.
    -d: allow version code downgrade.
```

---

For more then one **apk** file on Linux we can use `xargs` and on windows we can use `for loop`.
Linux / Unix sample :

```
ls -1 *.apk | xargs -I xxx adb install -r xxx
```

Answer (score 10):

Put the APK file into the tools folder in the Android SDK and give the path to tools in the command prompt and use the command:

```
adb install "name".apk file
```

Comment: if you dont have SDK of android install there is another way to install 3rd paty app

Comment: It doesn't work from tools folder, it has to be inside "platform-tools" rather.

Answer (score 8):

Directly connect your Android device and select the USB debugging option in the device.
Eclipse will itself find your device, and then just run the code.

Or alternatively, paste your APK file in the Android SDK platform-tools folder and from the command prompt install it like this:

```
D:......../platform-tools> adb install yourfile.apk.
```

Answer (score 4):

For debugging:

- Enable USB debugging on your phone (*settings* -> *applications* -> *development*).
- Connect your phone to the computer, and make sure you have the correct drivers installed.
- In Eclipse, run your project as an Android application (right click project -> *run as* -> *Android application*).

Installing the APK file:

- Export the APK file, make sure you sign it (right click project -> *Android tools* -> export signed application package).
- Connect your phone, USB debugging enabled.
- from the terminal, use [ADB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_Debug_Bridge) to install the APK file (`adb install path-to-your-apk-file.apk`).

Answer (score 2):

I was using the command prompt to manually install the .apk file on my device (Nexus 7) but the following should work in theory on any android device (after enabling the device for developer mode).  This method was becoming cumbersome so I created a simple batch file so now all I have to do is double-click it and it installs for me (device must be plugged in to my development machine).  Just create a text file and save it as .BAT with the following text (customize to accommodate your file paths):

```
cd C:\{**path to your install location**}\sdk\platform-tools

adb install C:\{**path to your .apk file**}\{**project/apk file name**}.apk
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have mutliple devices/emulators, the commands above may not work. So, try these steps

1. get device list by running `adb devices`. this will list devices and their IDs
2. install apk using `adb -s [DEVICE-ID] [-r|-l] <apk path>`

Ensure you unlock your device in the process.

Answer (score 0):

For what its worth, installing a system app to the `/system/app` directory will be:

```
adb push appname.apk /system/app/
```

Just ensure you're in the right directory where the target .apk file to be installed is, or you could just copy the .apk file to the `platform-tools` directory of the Android SDK and `adb` would definitely find it.