# Can I export my .apk to my phone just for testing?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to install apk file on android phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756451/how-to-install-apk-file-on-android-phone)

I finished the app on eclipse and I tested it on AVD now I want to export it to my phone just for testing not for market how can I do that, thanks a lot !

Comment: Of course you can. Google it. (There's also lots of info on this here on SO)

Comment: I really googled it couldnt find in-depth answer.... stack is not my first option at all

Comment: [I found this one by googling your title](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4756451/645270). Here's some info from [android dev](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/device.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in the bin directory inside your project folders. You can move it to your phone via dropbox or other means. I do it all the time.

You don't need to do the export wizard to just test. As long as you have the "allow unknown" checked in settings. Once the project has been built and run in the emulator there should be an apk file.

I used dropbox as my source control so my entire project is on dropbox which makes it very easy to test on phone. As long as you have dropbox installed on your phone you just navigate to the bin directory on your phone and download the apk from there.

Comment: I connect it via usb and press "Run" in eclipse, but this wireless version sounds nice.

Answer (score 2):

Other suggestion:

Connect your phone to your computer.
Run your project and eclipse will deploy it to your phone.

Comment: Though he needs to install specific drivers if he's on Windows. And might need to edit some file if he's on GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

There is an Export wizard, look in your AndroidManifest.xml file, from there you can create your apk, and then install it easily on your device.

Just place your APK file on your device.

Answer (score 0):

1. connect your phone via USB
2. open a shell and move to the platform-tools folder
3. sudo ./adb kill-server
4. sudo ./adb start-server
5. run your application in Eclipse and go choose your device